# Divide the application screen in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to divide the application screen into parts like one part is fixed showing fixed controls & another one is variable which can be changed when user select something. Like in Qt Creator we are having the left side column always fixed & the content of center screen is changing when user is selecting something. I have attached the screen shot. How to do it. if any one is having any idea please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you speak of the Qt Creator you certainly mean the controls on the left and right. In my opinion, the best thing to implement that are [QDockWidgets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qdockwidget.html). Have a look at them in the docs and as Martin said, look at the [examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/mainwindows-dockwidgets.html), they are perfect to learn each of the layout and composing issues.

QDockWidgets can be made floatable (undock them from the main window as toolboxes), they can have fixed sides to be docked on and it's easy to use them, because they can be filled with every widget you like. I often use them when I show a file explorer in an application, for example. Just look at the [examples](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/mainwindows-dockwidgets.html) and play with it.

If you just want to have QActions visible all the time for the user, you can use a [QToolBar](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtoolbar.html).

Comment: Oh and I forgot to mention that you could have a look at QSplitter, too. (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsplitter.html)

Answer (score 1):

You normally start with a QMainWindow and then put other toolbars, controls, widgets etc inside that.

Check out the Qt examples that come with the SDK src